# Tkinter: How to get written text from user using text widget and print them in multiple lines?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print this four line paragraph in three different lines but it always comes in a single line.

The code is as such:

```
def any():
    v = box.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    print(v)


box = Text(window,width=50,height=20,wrap = WORD)
box.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=15,pady=15)

btn = Button(window,text = 'Click',command = any).grid(row=0,column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

and in the text box I wrote :

```
Hello world myself Unknown Program Currently
programming with tkinter and wanna print this three
line code in multiple lines rather than a single
line.
```

What I got:

```
Hello world myself Unknown Program Currently pragraming with tkinter rand wanna print this three line code in multiple lines rather than a single line.
```

and it got printed in single line and I want to print it in 4 lines as it is in the text box.how can I do that?

Comment: The text in the widget is word-wrapping at a width of 50 characters. You could probably format the text you're getting in a similar manner using the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module.

Comment: If you entered the data as represented in this question -- with line breaks at then end of each of the four lines -- it simply cannot appear as a single line when you call `print`.  If it's appearing as a single line, then you simply must be inserting the data without newlines. Can you update your question to make this more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question makes it look like you've entered four lines of text (ie: text with newlines), the only explanation for the output is that you've entered a single long line of text which gets word-wrapped by the text widget.

If you want the printed output to match what you see due to word wrapping, you can iterate over each displayed line, printing them out one by one. Tkinter has a way to get the end of a displayed line by modifying an index with "display lineend". For example, `"1.0 display lineend"` will represent the position immediately after the last character on the displayed line.

You can use this to iterate over each displayed lines. Here is an example of how you might do it:

```
index = "1.0"
while box.compare(index, "<", "end"):
    text = box.get(index, f"{index} display lineend")
    print(text)
    index = box.index(f"{index} + 1 display line")
```

This starts at the index "1.0", gets everything up to the end of the first displayed line, and prints it. It then adjusts the starting index to the beginning of the next displayed line, and continues until the starting index is the same as the final index in the widget.